# Find pattern amongst Mysql entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the number of records that are greater than a specific float and find the group of data that repeat the most.

For **example**, I have the data below and I need to find how many entries have values > 4.

```
    1.5
    1.7
    4.5
    4.7
    4.8
    1.4
    4.5
    4.9
```

In the above data the longest continuous repetition of values greater than 4 is 4.5,4.7,4.8.

Therefore the total I would like returned should be 3.

As you can see the pattern breaks after 4.8 since the number is 1.4 above.

Is there a way to identify this pattern?

Comment: It looks difficult in pure MySQL, why not doing that with the resulting list of all values afterwards?

Comment: in which sequence you order the records ?

Comment: How is the data stored / passed to your query? Tables aren't intrinsically ordered; if that's in a table with an identity field though that could be used with a triangular join. If it's being passed in as delimited input, the input item position could be output alongside the value and used to the same end. But without knowing how the data comes in it's difficult to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

did you mean some thing like this ?

```
SELECT count(*) AS nr, IF(num >4,1,0) AS inRange,
@grpnr := IF (@lastval = @lastval:= IF(num >4,1,0),@grpnr,@grpnr+1 )  AS grpnr,
n.* , GROUP_CONCAT(n.num) AS numbers
FROM mynum n
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @grpnr:=0, @lastval:=0) AS parameter  
GROUP BY grpnr
ORDER BY id;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [who]> SELECT * from mynum;
+----+------+
| id | num  |
+----+------+
|  1 |  1.5 |
|  2 |  1.7 |
|  3 |  4.5 |
|  4 |  4.7 |
|  5 |  4.8 |
|  6 |  1.4 |
|  7 |  4.5 |
|  8 |  4.9 |
+----+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []> SELECT count(*) AS nr, IF(num >4,1,0) AS inRange,
    -> @grpnr := IF (@lastval = @lastval:= IF(num >4,1,0),@grpnr,@grpnr+1 )  AS grpnr,
    -> n.* , GROUP_CONCAT(n.num) AS numbers
    -> FROM mynum n
    -> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @grpnr:=0, @lastval:=0) AS parameter
    -> GROUP BY grpnr
    -> ORDER BY id;
+----+---------+-------+----+------+-------------+
| nr | inRange | grpnr | id | num  | numbers     |
+----+---------+-------+----+------+-------------+
|  2 |       0 | 0     |  1 |  1.5 | 1.5,1.7     |
|  3 |       1 | 1     |  3 |  4.5 | 4.5,4.7,4.8 |
|  1 |       0 | 2     |  6 |  1.4 | 1.4         |
|  2 |       1 | 3     |  7 |  4.5 | 4.5,4.9     |
+----+---------+-------+----+------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB []>
```